# How do I get an OG Group Menu block to appear in View?

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

Running Drupal 7 with `OG 7.x-2.3` and `OG Menu 7.x-3.0-rc4`.  I have added a view to a Group Menu that lists all content in the group.  All I want is for the group menu block to display when the view is executed.

I have added code in `hook_views_pre_view` to maintain the group context when view is executed.

I also attempt to utilize `OG URL Group Context Detection` by creating this URL path for the view:

`group/%/content`

I also added code in the view header/footer to detect if there is a group context when view executes.  There is.

Despite all this, I can not get the Group menu block to display when the view is executed.  Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issue, more or less, here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2195889#comment-8493709

1. First, setting all group views to use this url format: group/%/(title)
2. Always set group context in hook_views_pre_view() when arg(0) == 'group' and arg(1) is numeric.
   3 .Use hook_block_info() to create my own block.
3. Use hook_block_view() to make my block content equal that generated by og_menu_block_view().
4. Go into block settings, and set the block to only appear on views = group/%/(title).
5. Set the block to appear at the same weight (just above or below) as the OG Menu block.

And, voila!  When I click on view from  OG Menu, the OG group menu itself persists.